# PhpMyAdmin strange issue (most likely php)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, apache2

Today I tried to install phpmyadmin onto my ubuntu 22.04.3 server using apach2 running on port 81 but here is the issue: When is access my phpmyadmin panel it just returns this:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
   </head>
   <body>
      <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
         "?php
         declare(strict_types=1);
         use PhpMyAdmin\Routing;
         if (! defined('ROOT_PATH')) {
             // phpcs:disable PSR1.Files.SideEffects
             define('ROOT_PATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
             // phpcs:enable
         }
         global $route, $containerBuilder;
         require_once ROOT_PATH . 'libraries/common.inc.php';
         $dispatcher = Routing::getDispatcher();
         Routing::callControllerForRoute($route, $dispatcher, $containerBuilder);  "
      </pre>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now: I don't know what this really means + I don't know any php. Could somebody help me out here? :)

Comment: Check out adminer - it's much simplier than phpmyadmin (just a single file) and doesn't need installation. https://www.adminer.org/